# Attaching cells to CW complex yields a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

On page 352 of Hatcher's book, he claims that if we have a CW complex A, then attach some cells to it, what remains is a CW complex. The way he states it, it seems like this should be obvious. But given CW complexes are defined inductively, by attaching n cells to the n-1 skeleton, Hatcher's claim as stated is not obvious to me (he states no conditions on how the cells are attached to A). Is it obvious?

Comment: For anyone reading along in their copy of Hatcher who is confused by this question, this is referring to page 352 of the [most recent online edition](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html).  In my paper edition, the construction referred to in this question is instead on page 353.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a CW-complex and $\varphi:S^{k-1}\to A$ is a *cellular* map, then the space $A\cup_\varphi e^k$ obtained by attaching a map via $\varphi$ *is* a CW-complex.  The condition that $\varphi$ is cellular means that its image is contained in the $(k-1)$-skeleton $A^{k-1}$.  So actually, when building up $A\cup_{\varphi} e^k$ inductively as a cell complex, you could have added the new $k$-cell when you only had the $(k-1)$-skeleton, instead of adding it at the very end. This is why Hatcher specifies that the maps $\varphi_\alpha$ should be chosen to be cellular maps.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely clear explanation.

Comment: Eric, I have one more question that is somewhat related to the first, to make sure I understand this; Under the first heading 11.1.1 ("Attaching one more cell" here http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-127-prev.pdf in the b) condition the map from S^(n-1) to K is really a map from S^(n-1) to the n-1 skeleton of K, right? Otherwise we wouldn't necessarily have a CW complex.

Comment: Well, you don't have to state that to make Lemma 11.1 true, since omitting it gives a weaker statement.  But yes, if you examine the proof, you'll see that the map does land in the $(n-1)$-skeleton, and if it didn't, you couldn't be sure $L$ was a CW-complex.

Comment: Sure that's what I meant, the map has to land in the (n-1) skeleton to be certain it is a CW complex. Thank you for your help and patience.